# How to throw error in node js and catch it mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I cannot catch an error I throw in Node and catch it in mocha.
Please help!

**Node:**
Node code that throws error

```
app.put('/reviews/:id', (req, res) => {
    var db = req.db;
    Review.findById(req.params.id, 'title description', function (error, review) {
        if (error) {
            // console.error(error);
            throw new Error('some error');
        }
        review.title = req.body.title;
        review.description = req.body.description;
        review.save(function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            res.send({
                success: true
            })
        })
    })
})
```

**Mocha:** 
Mocha test

```
it('should throw exception for incorrect id', function (done) {
    let updateReview = {
        title: 'Updated Title',
        description: 'Updated Description'
    };
    chai.request(app)
        .get('/reviews')
        .end(function (err, res) {
            chai.request(app)
                .put('/reviews/12')
                .send(updateReview)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    expect(app).to.throw(Error);
                    done();
                });
        });
});
```

**Error:**
Error from the console.

Uncaught Error: some error

Comment: When you throw an error from your API code, it will not be propagate down to the HTTP response and to the client send the request. Instead what will happen is, the application breaks due to uncaught exception.

The way to handle errors is to send a NON SUCCESS HTTP CODE via the response of HTTP requests. There are lot of NON SUCCESS HTTP codes available in the HTTP spec. Please refer this link for them https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html
Send one of the error HTTP code as the respoonse, instead throwing error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't expect an error to be thrown at the end of your http call.

You could test the return code for a specific request by adding a response instead of the throw line as the following :

```
app.put('/reviews/:id', (req, res) => {
var db = req.db;
Review.findById(req.params.id, 'title description', function (error, review{
    if (error) {
        // console.error(error);
        return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    review.title = req.body.title;
    review.description = req.body.description;
    review.save(function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
        res.send({
            success: true
        })
    })
})
```

And by updating your test :

```
it('should throw exception for incorrect id', function (done) {
        let updateReview = {
            title: 'Updated Title',
            description: 'Updated Description'
        };
        chai.request(app)
            .get('/reviews')
            .end(function (err, res) {
                chai.request(app)
                    .put('/reviews/12')
                    .send(updateReview)
                    .end(function (err, res) {
                        expect(res).to.have.status(500);
                        done();
                    });
            });
    });
```

If you want to test that a specific error is thrown for a given function, then you should call expect with the function as parameter. This could be done by isolating your database call in a function, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.throw`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw) assertion only works on functions. More specifically: it should be passed a function reference, and when Chai calls that function, it expects that the function throws an error.

In your situation, `app` isn't a function, it's a reference to an Express application (it *may* be callable, but you're not testing the app function, you're testing how the app handles a particular request).

Throwing an error *inside an Express app* triggers [Express's error handler](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). It will handle the error by sending a HTTP 500 response.

You can test for this:

```
expect(res).to.have.status(500);
```